# React-easy-sort gives back a .map err

Tags: reactjs

I hope you can help me out, i have been trynig to find the awnser however i have not found it on stack with the libraries i am using

I am trying to implement react-easy-sort using JS

```
const [items, setItems] = useState(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'])

const onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}) => {
  setItems(({items}) => ({
    items: arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex),
  }));
};
```

To return:

```
<SortableList onSortEnd={onSortEnd} className="list" draggedItemClassName="dragged">
  {items.map((item) => (
     <SortableItem key={item}>
        <div className="item">{item}</div>
     </SortableItem>
   ))}
</SortableList>
```

However when dragging on of the values from place to place I get the following error:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 'onSortEnd' fucntion you set items state as an object with property items that is your array (you cannot map over object) and also you destructure state as object but the state does not have property items. Instead you should set the state as an array like this (assuming your 'arrayRemove' function returns an an array) and according to the docs you should use arrayMoveImmutable if using with React or create shallow copy of the array and library's onSortEnd does not use object as an argument:

```
import { arrayMoveImmutable } from 'array-move'

const onSortEnd = (oldIndex, newIndex) => {  
 setItems((items) => {
   return arrayMoveImmutable(items, oldIndex, newIndex)
   // or shallow copy
  return arrayMove([...items], oldIndex, newIndex)
});
```

Or one-liner:

```
const onSortEnd = (oldIndex, newIndex) =>                
  setItems((items) => arrayMoveImmutable(items, oldIndex, newIndex))
```

Comment: @radmin.1 than you for your response however using,  (sorry arrayRemove should have been arrayMove

const onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}) => {
    setItems(({items}) => arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex));
  };


i get the following error: TypeError: array is not iterable

Comment: instead of setItems(({items})=>...) you shoud just do setItems((items)=>...). Because with curly brackets you are destructuring an object with property items but items is an array not an object.

Comment: That fixis the issue however, now when i am draging and dropping it goes back to the first sort position.

changed it to:

const onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}) => {
    setItems((items)=> arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex) )
  };

Comment: That will be an issue with the arrayRemove function itself. The original issue is solve. Please provide your arrayRemove function.

Comment: Hello, i am using arrayMove i already changed my code,

Comment: With react you should use 'arrayMoveImmutable' instead 'array move' due to how React works. I have edited my answer.

Comment: When i am using arrayMoveImmutable the sort does not change it will go back to the initial sort

Comment: I'm referring the library docs. Either you install package 'array-move' and import from that or you can create shallow copy of the array and use that: setItems((items) => arrayMoveImmutable([...items], oldIndex, newIndex)); According to docs  you do not destructure onSortEnd function arguments (it is not an object):  const onSortEnd = (oldIndex: number, newIndex: number) => {
    setItems((array) => arrayMoveImmutable(array, oldIndex, newIndex))
  }

Comment: Hello, still goes back to the inititial sort :( using:

const onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}) => {
    setItems((items) => arrayMoveImmutable([...items], oldIndex, newIndex));
  };

i have array-move installed

Comment: Use without curly brackets: const onSortEnd = (oldIndex, newIndex) =>...

Comment: I am using javascript, trying to avoid typsescript since i am not very familiar with that

Comment: That's fine but please always refer to docs of the library you are using.

Comment: If it works now you can accept the answer if you think it helped you.

Comment: In my question it was stated i am using Javascript and it is not working for me no.. i really appricate the help but how to accept the awnser if it is not working yet.

Comment: The just remove the types, I edited the answer.

Comment: Sir i salute you! you are my hero ,... maybe abreak after (trying to code, since i am a newby) 10 hours will help ... many thanks again!

Comment: For a newbie, mistakes are always the best way to learn :). Advice again: when using third party libraries always read to the docs especially if you have issues.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think that your problem comes from setItems.
You can try with this function:

```
const onSortEnd = ({ oldIndex, newIndex }) => {
  setItems((prevItems) => {
    const newItems = arrayMove(prevItems, oldIndex, newIndex);
    return newItems;
  });
```